# Removing any character besides 0-9 + - / * and ^

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to further my understanding of regular expressions in JavaScript.

So I have a form that allows a user to provide any string of characters.  I'd like to take that string and remove any character that isn't a number, parenthesis, +, -, *, /, or ^.  I'm trying to write a negating regex to grab anything that isn't valid and remove it.  So far the code concerning this issue looks like this:

```
var pattern = /[^-\+\(\)\*\/\^0-9]*/g;
function validate (form) {
    var string = form.input.value;
    string.replace(pattern, '');
    alert(string);
};
```

This regex works as intended on http://www.infobyip.com/regularexpressioncalculator.php regex tester, but always alerts with the exact string I supply without making any changes in the calculator.  Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to escape everything inside of a character set: `/[^-+()^*\/0-9]/g`.

Comment: @Blender: <del>You do need to escape that forward slash inside of a regular expression, though.</del> (And although I suppose it’s probably for clarity, the `^` doesn’t need escaping either.)

Comment: @minitech: Oddly enough, that didn't trouble the JS regex engine. Thanks.

Comment: @minitech: Actually I was wondering the same thing, but I tried it in Chrome and it worked just fine without any escaping.

Comment: @MarkByers: Really? Fancy that, I thought it was just a problem in VIM. I guess JavaScript’s regular expressions are smarter than they let on :)

Answer (score 10):

The `replace` method doesn't modify the string. It creates a new string with the result of the replacement and returns it. You need to assign the result of the replacement back to the variable:

```
string = string.replace(pattern, '');
```

Comment: Wow.  Thank you.  I was so focused on the regex, I missed the obvious.